# Vakil 11.2.A: Transitivity of an equivalence relation involving composita of fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm working on Vakil's "Rising Sea" notes for an independent study. In Exercise 11.2.A, he gives a relation between intermediate field extensions. If $E/F$ is a field extension, and $F'$ and $F''$ are intermediate field extensions, then $F'\sim F''$ if $F'F''$ is algebraic over both $F'$ and $F''$. Here $F'F''$ is the *compositum* of $F'$ and $F''$, the smallest field extension in $E$ containing $F'$ and $F''$.

He asks to show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Reflexivity and symmetry are obvious, but I'm having trouble showing transitivity. I'm not sure about how knowing that $F'F''$ is algebraic over both $F'$ and $F''$, and knowing that $F''F'''$ is algebraic over both $F''$ and $F'''$ gives us that $F'F'''$ is algebraic over both $F'$ and $F'''$.

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. If $x\in F'F'''$, how can we show that $x$ is algebraic over $F'$ *and* algebraic over $F'''$?

Comment: If $x \in F'F'''$ and $x \in F'F''$ and $x \in F''F'''$, then clearly $x$ is algebraic over $F'$ and algebraic over $F'''$. What happens, for example, if $x \in F'$ but $x \notin F'''$?

Comment: Let
$x\in F'F'''$. If $x\in F'$, $x$ is algebraic over $F'$, so it
is the root of a polynomial with coefficients in $F'$, each of which
is the root of a polynomial with coefficients in $F''$, each of which
is the root of a polynomial with coefficients in $F'''$. So $x$
is algebraic in $F'''$. And similarly, if $x\in F'''$, then $x$
is algebraic over $F'$.

What about the case where $x \notin F'$ and $x \notin F'''$?

Comment: In general, if $x\in F'F'''$, then $x$
can be expressed as a polynomial in $F'$ and $F'''$, each term of
which, we have shown is algebraic in $F'$ and $F'''$.

Comment: That completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

One way to interpret this is by noting that $F' \sim F''$ is equivalent to the statement "every element of $F'$ is algebraic over $F''$, and vice versa."

To see this, suppose first that $F' \sim F''$. Then if $a \in F'$, we know $a \in F'F''$, which we are assuming is algebraic over $F''$, and so $a$ is algebraic over $F''$; similarly if $b \in F''$ then $b$ is algebraic over $F'$. Conversely, suppose every element of $F'$ is algebraic over $F''$ and vice versa. We know any element $c \in F'F''$ can be written as a rational function of elements of $F'$ and elements of $F''$, and that a rational function of elements algebraic over a field is again algebraic (since the set of algebraic elements over a given base field is a field), and since all elements of $F', F''$ are algebraic over both $F', F''$, we have that $c$ is algebraic over $F'$ and $F''$.

Once we've interpreted the equivalence relation like this, transitivity becomes easy.